# How to get record count from $resource returned object ?

Tags: angularjs, count, ngresource

I am using angular-resource to get my data from the server, and here is the code

```
var app = angular.module('app',[...]);

    app.factory('propertiesService', ['$resource', 'CONSTANTS',  function($resource, CONSTANTS) {
        var _default_url = CONSTANTS.HTTP.API_URL+"/properties/get";
        return $resource(_default_url);
    }]);
```

Then I get it in my controller

```
app.controller('propertiesSearchController', ['$scope' ,'$rootScope','propertiesService', function($scope, $rootScope, propertiesService) {
        $scope.properties = propertiesService.get();

    }]);
```

but now in my views, I cant get the length to know how many records it returned

```
e.g {{ properties.length}}
```

However I am able to use ng-repeat to get the data in the view.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be easy, I was returning OBJECT not ARRAY and .length was not working for it. Converting it to ARRAY worked.

Answer (score -2):

the resource service works with callbacks, so a proper way to do it is(assuming your resource endpoint is working):

```
app.controller('propertiesSearchController', ['$scope' ,'$rootScope','propertiesService', function($scope, $rootScope, propertiesService) {
    propertiesService.query(function(data) {
        $scope.prperties = data;
        console.log(data.length);
    });

}]);
```